# Can I edit previous commits to ignore a large file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I started am R.project and made 5 commits locally. I went to push to github, but have the following errors:

> remote: error: Trace:
> 0f04f657da56cd2cf86526f44eae8995d1ae359b6e251f112da0794686a722e3
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote:
> error: File
> data/v-2021/AIRS.2006.12.31.L3.RetStd001.v6.0.9.0.G13155192744.hdf is
> 380.41 MB; thisexceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File
> Storage -

I don't actually want this file backed up so I added *.hdf to .gitignore and ran

> git rm --cached *.hdf

Having confirmed this because it is still associated with the previous commits I tried

> git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.hdf' HEAD

but get the same errors

I have also tried

> git rebase -i HEAD~2

but I think I got the interactive part wrong and it deleted my code back 3 commits, so now it freaks me out. (yes I do have a backup)

Is there a way I can remove this file from being tracked in my previous, local commits so I can push to github *in a Newb-friendly way*?

Comment: You're right that it's because it's associated with previous commits! This answer here seem like what you want to do, and it allows you to do it without installing any other tools! Good luck!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274113/4967403

Comment: Alternatively, if you're willing to install something, git filter-repo is a tool designed to do this job. The installation looks pretty simple, and once it's installed you should be able to do this with `git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match <filename>`. More details are provided in the original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/4967403

the install process is also described here, but there's a chance it's already on your system! https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md

Comment: I had not found those, but I am struggling to apply those solutions to mine. I tried:
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.hdf' HEAD
but get the same errors. 
I had also tried to work with git rebase -i but don't understand it. I made a mess of it and it deleted half my code, so now it freaks me out.

Comment: Since you're trying to remove all hdf files from git, try --path-glob instead of path-match: `git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-glob '*.hdf'`

You need to use the single quotes around `'*.hdf'` to pass it verbatim to the command.

Comment: Also make a backup of the hdf files if you don't want to lose them

Comment: As I was unsure whether --path-glob would get rid of all .hdf files from other .git projects, and because of the specifics of this situation (there were no commits pushed to github yet and all my code is thoroughly documented as an Rnotebook -code lab book of sorts), the easiest solution was to unhide and delete the .git folder and initialise a new one which I was then able to push to my github repo. 
Although it didn't work out for me in this instance, thank you for your advice @Alecto Irene Perez

Comment: It will only get rid of files in the repository you run it in. I'm sorry we weren't able to keep your commits, but I'm happy you were still able to find a solution!

Comment: OK, thats really good to know for if I am daft in the same way again!

Comment: Good luck with your work!